# Sql Server 2008 R2 table columns and default values

Tags: sql-server

What is the point of default values in a column of a table?
According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx

> You can specify a default value that will be entered in the column in
>   SQL Server 2012 by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL.
>   If you do not assign a default value and the user leaves the column
>   blank, then:
>
> - If you set the option to allow null values, NULL will be inserted into the column.
> - If you do not set the option to allow null values, the column will remain blank, but the user will not be able to save the row until they
>     supply a value for the column.

I don't get it! If you don't allow nulls on a column surely it should insert a default value in that column if not supplied by the user.
So why doesn't it?

Comment: Is your question what is the point of default values, or that you are trying to use them are are unsuccessful?

Comment: As your statement says -- that only applies if you have not specified a default value -- what exactly is your point?  It can't insert a default value if none was specified.

Comment: Well if you do supply a default on a column which does not allow nulls then leave the column blank it wont insert a the default value.

Comment: @Paul yes, it will. Where are you reading that?

Comment: @Lamak doh your right!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have missed a part of the doc.

> You can specify a default value that will be entered in the column in
>   SQL Server 2012 by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL.
>   **If you do NOT assign a default value** and the user leaves the column
>   blank, **then**: If you set the option to allow null values, NULL will be
>   inserted into the column. If you do not set the option to allow null
>   values, the column will remain blank, but the user will not be able to
>   save the row until they supply a value for the column.

So if you DO assign a default value, it will be used as assignment when user leaves the column blank.

The "little bit weird thing" is that the doc explains first what will happen if you don't use the DEFAULT (which is probably not what you're waiting for : you'd like to know what will happen when you use it). Have also been confused at my first "too fast" reading.

Comment: The doc explains first what will happen if you do use the DEFAULT: ***"You can specify a default value that will be entered in the column in SQL Server 2012"*** but in a single line and has much more explanation for what happens if you don't :)

Comment: @ypercube well, yes, but it's partially wrong... It should be at least something like that "You can specify a default value that will be entered in the column in Sql Server 2012 **if you leave the column blank**"